# How to use UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have made a simple web browser for the iPhone but I would really like to be able to pinch to zoom in and out with the UIPinchGestureRecognizer, but I don't know how to use it. Could someone explain to me how to implement it in my code? If you have a link to a good explanation of this that would be very much appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to implement it at all? `UIWebView` already supports pinch-zooming natively.

Comment: Really? hmmm... when I built the app to my iPhone it wouldn't let me pinch at all. It wouldn't be that big of a deal if it formatted the whole page, but it zoomed in to a small square of the page and it is quite hard to do anything.

Comment: The page itself can disable pinch-zooming through the use of a particular `<meta>` tag, but if it hasn't done that, then UIWebView should behave very similarly to how Safari behaves.

Comment: Ok, thanks! the site has: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">` and some `<meta name=...>`. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Try navigating your custom browser to Amazon.com and seeing if you can zoom their. You should be able to.

Comment: @Adam The meta tag in question looks like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=600, initial-scale=2, user-scalable=no">`. The important bit here is the name `"viewport"` and the content value `user-scalable=no`. This is what prevents pinch-resizing on iOS. However, this meta tag also affects MobileSafari, so if you can't pinch-resize in your `UIWebView` then you shouldn't be able to do so from MobileSafari either.

Comment: Thanks for all of the information! I figured out the problem (really dumb mistake...). I forgot to check "Scales to fit page" for the UIWebView. It didn't pinch for amazon so I figured I did something wrong. Sorry about that and thanks for the help! =]

Answer (score 0):

For all the stuff you need for gesture recognizer's, look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Basically, you set up a gesture for your view, and add a selector method that would get called if the view recognizes that gesture. In this case, when it detects a pinch, you would tell the view to change size to your liking.

This, however, is the hard way of doing it though, as the pinch gesture is already associated with a UIWebView (not to mention, the MKMapView as well). You should probably look at [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219685/how-can-i-enable-zoom-in-on-uiwebview-which-inside-the-uiscrollview) to see what you need to do. Any search on google will also point you in the right direction. Hope that helps!