# UIWebView scrolling and zooming

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiwebview, scroll, zooming

I minimized a UIWebView so that it can just show a specific object from that side. My question is, how can I scroll to it, an how can I make it bigger without touching it?

Answer (score 1):

`UIWebView` has a `scrollView` property of type `UIScrollView`. This property lets you manipulate the current position, the current zoom level, and so on:

```
[myWebView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGMakePoint(x, y) animated:YES];
[myWebView.scrollView setZoomScale:newScale animated:YES];
```

Comment: @ViperOSX Enabling zoom is more complex. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2936558/335858) on web view - specific info, and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3657531/335858) on generic scroll view zooming.