# iPhone viewport not responding - webpage zoomed top left every time

Tags: iphone, html, css, asp-classic, viewport

I have been racking my brain trying to figure this out and I have searched all over this site and others and have found numerous solutions, none of which have any effect. I have tried the viewport meta tag in numerous configurations, I have tried removing the fb-root div, making sure there is no height=100%, and so on... nothing seems to make this page open at full width and size.

Comment: what you have tried yet.

Comment: May this link will be helpful to you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219685/how-can-i-enable-zoom-in-on-uiwebview-which-inside-the-uiscrollview

Comment: try the link I have just given

Comment: I reviewed the 2219685 issue and not sure it pertains to this issue, but reviewing it again now and seeing if I can pull something from it. Thanks for the responses so far.

Seems to be still locking to the upper left portion of the site fully zoomed in.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue... I literally went file by file and just noticed this little tid bit of code in one of the Highslide files (mobile.js)... simply removed and now all works like I wanted it to.

// Add a meta tag to have the iPhone render the page 1:1
        hs.createElement('meta', {
            name: 'viewport',
            content: 'width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;'
        }, null, document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]);