# How to enable zooming/pinch on UIWebView in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I have a WebView into which I'm loading a web page. I want to allow the user to zoom in on the web page in a similar fashion as they would with the web browser.
Any ideas how to enable this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I enable zoom in on UIWebView which inside the UIScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219685/how-can-i-enable-zoom-in-on-uiwebview-which-inside-the-uiscrollview)

Comment: just set scalesPageToFit=YES

Answer (score 0):

Set scalesPageToFit=YES and also checkout the answers here:

[How can I enable zoom in on UIWebView which inside the UIScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219685/how-can-i-enable-zoom-in-on-uiwebview-which-inside-the-uiscrollview)

[Enable zooming/pinch on UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134576/enable-zooming-pinch-on-uiwebview)

[Enable zooming/pinch on UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134576/enable-zooming-pinch-on-uiwebview/36270344)

Answer (score 0):

First add the webview delegate  , then add this codes.

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad 
    {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      self.Your_WebView.scalesPageToFit=YES;
    }

 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
    {
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     [self.Your_WebView.scrollView setZoomScale:3.0 animated:YES];

    }
```